# Different configurations for ssh client depending on ip address or hostname

Tags: ssh, configuration, password

I have this in my ~/.ssh/config directory:

```
Host 12.34.56.78
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_identity_file
```

When I ssh to 12.34.56.78, everything works fine. I'm asked for the passphrase for "my_identity_file" and I can connect to the server.

However, sometimes I'd also like to ssh to another server.
But whatever the server, if I do:

```
ssh account@anotherserver.com
```

I'm also asked for the passphrase for "my_identity_file" (even though the server has a different ip address). This is very annoying because I don't have the public key for this file set up on all my servers. I'd like to connect to this other server (an old shared hosting account) with a password, and now I cant.

How do I manage to use the key authentication only with one server, and keep using password by default for servers that aren't listed in my ~/.ssh/config ?

Comment: Is my_identity_file the actual name of the file or is it identity, id_dsa or id_rsa? Those are the default names that ssh looks for.

Comment: "my_identity_file" is the actual filename. I'm not using any of the default key names. I'm surprised that the ssh client wants to use that key while I thought I made it clear in the config file that I only wanted to use this key when connecting to the ip 12.34.56.78.

Comment: That's interesting. As an aside though if you just hit enter on the passphrase prompt ssh will skip the key and drop back to prompting for password auth.

Comment: What do you see if you run `ssh -v account@anotherserver.com`? Near the top ssh should spit out some information about what config sections (if any) it is applying. That might tell you something. (You can go up to -vvv for even more debugging information if you want to see if anything else useful shows up.)

Comment: When I type enter at the passphrase prompt, nothing happens (the ssh client quits and I'm back to the shell prompt). The same happens with the -v option.

Comment: Ooops. I just realized it comes from the way I configured ssh-add. Nothing to do with the ssh client config itself. I guess I'm going to delete my question.

Comment: Are you being asked for the ssh-add unlock passphrase and not your key passphrase or something?

Comment: No, actually, I had created this alias: `alias ssh='( ssh-add -l > /dev/null || ssh-add ~/.ssh/my_identity_file ) && ssh'` so that I'm only asked my passphrase once. And I had completely forgotten about the ssh command being an alias on my computer. No wonder, then, that I was asked my passphrase no matter the args I passed to the ssh command.

Comment: I wouldn't have expected that to happen with a loaded agent (but definitely with an unloaded one) and yeah, that will certainly confuse things greatly.

Answer (score 1):

The Host in the config file is actually the short name you want to identify the server as. You need to use hostname to identify by hostname or IP.
Also you can limit to a given user as well

Try something like

```
Host myhost
Hostname a.b.c.d
User myuser
Identityfile my-identity-file
```

This should use that key file only for the specified hostname
It will also use that user if you do not specify one

Answer (score 0):

You will probably find useful using a tool such as "ssh-add" that will keep your deciphered private key in memory, so it won't ask for your passphrase when you need it.

So, when you will want to ssh another host,

1/ If your public key is on it, ssh will authentificate you automatically

2/ If your public key isn't on it, ssh will try to authenticate you with the key, will fail, then ask you for the password.

But as said by Etan Reisner, it looks like you called your identity file by the default name, otherwise ssh wouldn't be trying using it. If you don't want to use an ssh agent, just change the name of your private key

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I'm already using ssh-add, so I'm only asked for this passphrase once. But why does the ssh client want to use this key while I only mentionned it in the 12.34.56.78 section of my config file?